# PHP - getting error message on submit when no error is present

Tags: php, email

so I have built this email form, which is supposed to display the error message 'name and email are mandatory' if the name or/ and email are not submitted.  However I am getting the same message if they are.  How can that be fixed?

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit-enquiry']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$guest_email = $_POST['email'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$message = $_POST['enquiry-message'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($guest_email)) 
{
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Name and email are mandatory")';
    echo '</script>';
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Bad Email Value")';
    echo '</script>';
    exit;
}

$email_from = $guest_email;//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Enquiry from $name";
$email_body = "Name: $name. \n". "Mobile: $mobile .\n". "Message:      $message. \n";

$to = "my_email";//<== update the email address 
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $guest_email \r\n"; 
/ /Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: enquiry.php');

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
   $injections = array('(\n+)',
          '(\r+)',
          '(\t+)',
          '(%0A+)',
          '(%0D+)',
          '(%08+)',
          '(%09+)'
          );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
  {
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }
}

 ?>
```

The html of the fprm:

```
<div id="enquiry-form">
                    <form method="post" name="enquiry-form" action="" target="_self">
                        <span class="short-input" id="name">
                            <h6>name</h6>
                            <input type="text" name="name">
                        </span>
                        <span class="short-input" id="mobile">
                            <h6>mobile</h6>
                            <input type="text" name="mobile">
                        </span>
                         <span class="long-input" id="email">
                            <h6>e-mail</h6>
                            <input type="text" name="email">
                        </span>
                        <span class="long-input" id="enquiry-message">
                            <h6>enquiry</h6>
                            <textarea name="enquiry-message"></textarea>
                        </span>

                </div>
                <div id="contact-info">
                    <h2>Contact Details</h2>
                </div>
                 <button type="submit" id="submit-enquiry" name="submit-enquiry">send</button>
               </form>
```

Comment: Can you do a dump of $_POST?

Are you sure your form isn't using GET instead of POST?

Perhaps show us the HTML for the form as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if( (empty($name)) || (empty($guest_email)) )
```

for more infos : [php  operation precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if( $name=='' || $guest_email=='' )
```

empty in some cases can lead to unexpected results. My experience led me to say that for a form validation it is better to check if the variable is empty in this way. Then you check the content of the variable (to see for example if it is a valid email) so this is safe enough for me. 
If your code still doesn't work then it is necessary to do further investigations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: you are right. I posted my answer in a mistake, while I was on the phone and it was missing part of the text. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if( empty(trim($name)) || empty(trim($guest_email)) )
```